# How to use the iNotes Calendar with a custom rest service

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to use a custom rest service to populate a iNotes calendar control. The rest service is returning the json that I need, but no matter what I do, it does not populate the calendar. Looking at the extlib demo did not really shed any light on the issue either.

Added - I want to use a non mail application so I have the necessary fields to use on a calendar view. But the main reason I want a custom view rest service is to be able to filter based on location and department.

Below is the code for my xPage which has a REST control, and CalendarStore Control, and and iNotes CalendarView Control. I also added in a entry returned by the rest service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="inoteslegacyjson">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewJsonLegacyService viewName="Calendar">
            <xe:this.columns>
                <xe:restViewColumn columnName="DEPT" loaded="true"
                    name="dept">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                <xe:restViewColumn columnName="startDate"
                    name="CalendarDateTim" loaded="true">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                <xe:restViewColumn columnName="$147" loaded="true"
                    name="Subject">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
            </xe:this.columns>
        </xe:viewJsonLegacyService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
<xe:notesCalendarStore id="notesCalendarStore1"
    dojoType="xpagesext.CalendarStore">
<xe:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:dojoAttribute name="pathInfo" value="/inoteslegacyjson">
    </xp:dojoAttribute>
</xe:this.dojoAttributes></xe:notesCalendarStore>
<xe:calendarView id="calendarView1"
    storeComponentId="notesCalendarStore1" type="M">
</xe:calendarView></xp:view>

{
@timestamp: "20140122T180515"
@toplevelentries: "58"
    -viewentry: [
      -{
      @unid: "85257C210070DA5C85257C24006DD996"
      @noteid: "8FA"
      @position: "1"
      @read: "true"
      @siblings: "58"
-entrydata: [
-{
@columnnumber: "0"
@name: "dept"
-text: {
0: "Information Services"
}
}
-{
@columnnumber: "1"
@name: "CalendarDateTim"
-datetime: {
0: "20131129T180515"
}
}
-{
@columnnumber: "2"
@name: "Subject"
-text: {
0: "Linda Berry - PTO"
}
}
]
}
```

Comment: Please add the essential parts of your code to your question.

Comment: You may also want to split this into two questions - one for the data not displaying and another for tweaking the styling... if you do create a separate question for the latter issue, replace phrases like "bit more responsive" and "certain size" with some additional specificity. ;)

Comment: It sounds like your scenario may be doing something totally different that what is being tried out on those pages "/XPagesExt.nsf/DWA_iNotesRest.xsp", or "/XPagesExt.nsf/DWA_LocalCalendarView.xsp", right? If so, we might have a bug here.

Comment: I added the page code which has everything that should be needed. I am also removed the part of the responsive functionalityh. I just want to concetrate of getting it to work with the data

Comment: Have a look in the intrapages project, it is not working perfect but you might get an idea or two. http://intrapages.openntf.org

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Tim to split your question into two separate ones. I know the issue with the view not responding to the window size. So if you open your calendar in a smaller window and want to change to full screen the calendar stay's small and add's some white space. Here my short solution for the this problem:

To make your iNotesCalendar more responsive you can connect a function to your window using dojo add this code on the bottom of your xPage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeCalendar() {
        cview.resize();
    };

    dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
         dojo.connect(window, 'resize',resizeCalendar);
    });
</script>
```

This Client script will call the resize function of your calendar object when ever your window gets resized. The `cview` is the `jsId` of your  `<xe:calendarView id="calendarView" jsId="cview">`.

2) Your Json entrydata[] seems a bit small. Does your calendar view regonize your store? Add a jsId to your `<xe:calendarView>` Use Firebug there in the DOM tab under jsId._stores[0].items you should find all your calendar entries for the current viewing month. If there is no item displaying your json is invalid or missing data. If you can see items check there data startDateTime, type, subject, unid... if something is missing or invalid.